# Opening the ringtone setting screen

Tags: java, android, ringtone

In my project I want to open the phone ringtone setting screen from the application. How can I do it like below image by code?

[image: This image is the expaml]

Comment: add what you are tried

Comment: Simple i open the ringtone setting screen given above image

Answer (score 0):

In android you need to trigger intents to access something outside of your application .
To trigger ringtones intent you have to trigger ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER.

Find more info here .

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager#ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER

Comment: I also use this feature and my downloadable ringtones are shown in ringtone picker but its not set the default ringtone

Comment: Do you want to download a ringtone and set it ?

Comment: yes i want to download from Url and set on phone default ringtone!

Comment: i also use the ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER but i dosen't work

Comment: The download ringtone is successflly and show in the ringtone picker but it's not make phone default ringtone